# French character issue using asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web, asp.net-web-api

I have the following problem when I make a request to an asp.net web api controller.

I submit the following text: VIDÉO, but when it gets to my controller action the text become: VID�O.

the problem is not when the data is posted to the server because I can see that the json data that is being posted to the server is correct. 
I tried all variation of the utf-8 character set but still have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please look into below link.It may be resolved your issue.

[MVC Basic Site: Step 1 – Multilingual Site Skeleton](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526827/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-Multilingual-Site-Skeleton)

[Multilingual MVC Application With Customized JS Bundles Based on User Language](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/multilingual-mvc-application-with-customized-js-bundles-base/)